# Split lists in batches

Tags: php

This may sound simple but sometimes its the simple things that are quite harder to achieve. At least I can't find a proper way to do this clean with PHP and I searched different functions.

I have a lists of items I read from a file. For example:

```
foreach(file('items.txt') as $line) {
// Do something here with $line;
}
```

Assuming this text list (which is read line by line) has a specific number of items, 50, or 10,000 or 9,444, how can I split them into smaller batches?

For example split them into batches of 100 each. I basically want to read items.txt and write the items into smaller files, for example items1.txt, items2.txt, items3.txt, and so on. Each containing the same number of items, except the last file that contain less as we don't know the total numbers of items to split.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/split perhaps

Comment: So what is the problem? You want to do it with php or with command line as already written in previous comment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read part of a file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478102/read-part-of-a-file-in-php) don't worry about mp3 in the question. works the same with txt files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-chunk.php) to automatically split your array of lines into sub-arrays of a specific size.

Examples

```
$chunks = array_chunk(file('items.txt'), 100);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
   foreach($chunk as $line) {
   // Do something here with $line;
   }
}
```

Comment: This only works for arrays already in memory, it will not work if you're trying to chunk a file that's too big to fit in memory.

Comment: true, but that is not part of this question

Comment: True but I feel that this is a disclaimer that is worth noting.

Comment: Actually, apokryfos is correct. The main reason to split into batches is the list is enormous and would probably not fit into memory eventually. Smaller batches can be processed. I tried to keep the question as short and simple as possible.

Comment: 10000 or even 100000 items are not really enormous. But I agree with the rest. @nibb11

Comment: Well, then you need to add that important requirement to your question. This would only be a problem if your text files are like 10+ MB each and you wont to process several in the same file.

Comment: Ok, this may work. I guess processing 500,000 items or more this way is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a counter variable which counts how many lines you’ve added. Whenever it reaches your threshold you should do something with that data and afterwards clean the array and reset the counter to zero.

This also depends on what you’re trying to achieve. If your’re getting an out of memory error half way through, due to something like sending an email every iteration. You might solve it by adding a delay (sleep) after every action.

Hope this helps you.