# How to Read some files parts with php

Tags: php

I need to get the value of start, end and md5 hash when reading a file and then insert it into a database. It works very fine
 when reading the entire files and values are properly inserted into database.

Now lets say I have a file of about **883mb** and I want to read the last **880mb** while excluding the first **3mb**.

How can I achive that.(That is Reading from remaining **4mb up to 883mb** and inserts its corresponding values to database)

solution I find here just reads the last 1mb of the file
[Read part of a file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478102/read-part-of-a-file-in-php)

Here is the working code when reading the entire files

```
   $fragSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // chunk 1 mb
       $file = file_get_contents('mydata.zip'); //about 883mb
        $fileSize = strlen($file);
        $numFragments = ceil($fileSize / $fragSize);
        $i = 0;

        while ($i < $numFragments) {
            $chunkSize = $fragSize;
            $start = $i * $fragSize;
            $end = $i * $fragSize + $chunkSize - 1;
            $offset = $i * $fragSize;

            if ($stream = fopen('mydata.zip', 'r')) {

// you have to chunk the files to avoid memory issues
                $data = stream_get_contents($stream, $chunkSize);
                fclose($stream);
            }
          $hash = md5($data);

           // insert start, end and hash value to database

    // pdo connection
    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO data1
    (start_read,end_read,hash_read)

                              values
    (:start_read,:end_read,:hash_read)');

    $statement->execute(array( 

    ':start_read' => $start,
    ':end_read' => $end,
    ':hash_read' => $hash       
    ));


        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the data twice. One with `file_get_contents` and others with `fread`. No need for that. I guess you want the 4th MB, and the last MB, and the hash of the whole file to be inserted to the database. You can do it this way:

```
// set filename to a variable
$filename = "mydata.zip";
// open the file for reading
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
// set the cursor position where the 3rd MB ends
fseek($f, 3 * 1024 * 1024, SEEK_SET);
// read 1MB of data
$first = fread($f, 1024);
// set the cursor position to the start of last MB
fseek($f, -1024, SEEK_END);
// read 1MB of data
$last = fread($f, 1024);
// get the hash of the file    
$hash = md5($file);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Taha Paksu for your response. Am seeing reading of
 the last 1 mb in your answer but what I want is this. 

lets assume that the files is 883mb. Then I first read 3mb of mydata.zip yesterday which left us with remaining 880mb,
 Now i want to read the remaining files today so i should start reading from 4mb until get to the last which is 883mb.
 so instead of reading the file afresh, i will continue reading from where i stop and thats why i pass it in a while loop.

And as it loop I then insert values into database until the files finish reading.
 please can you help further

Comment: Also like I said above I need to continue inserting the values of each start, end and hash individually as it loops until the files finish reading or get finished just like i did in the while loop. thanks waiting to hear from you

Comment: Hello @Henrymart, the code I've given includes the knowledge to get you to what you want. Do you want a whole working code to copy/paste directly?